# Recapture Hard Drive Space

Tags: updates

Ihave tried several versions of linux on my Vista Windows Dell Inspirion E1705 laptop.  Each time I have installed a Linux OS from the magazine DVD I have used a portion of my C drive to do so.  How do I reallocate these drive partitions back to the Windows portion of the drive or use them for other Linux trials?

Answer (score 0):

1. To give back to windows you need to delete installed linux partition and then reload windows boot loader.

from manage devices - disk management - you can extend or add to windows from windows.

note: after removing linux unless you restore windows boot loader you wont boot.

1. to use for other linux distros testing you can choose the partition as installed one from manual choice or ssomething else at partition step.

hope that helps.